# Proving that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{m}{n^k}$ converges to $\frac{m}{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I would appreciate any feedback about the correctness of the proof and some potential other techniques!
Proposition: Let $m, n \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $\vert n \vert \gt 1.$ Then the series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{m}{n^k}$ converges to $\dfrac{m}{n-1}$.

Proof: We observe, that this is a geometric series in the form of $m\times n^{-k}$. Since the series is a geometric series, which converges, (EDIT) because if $\vert n \vert \gt 1$, then $\vert \frac{1}{n}\vert \lt 1$. Thus, we can use the geometric series test to first, find the common ration and then compute the sum. The common ratio, $r=\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, after substituting $a_n$, we have: $\frac{m}{n^2}:\frac{m}{n}$ $\implies \frac{mn}{n^2 m}$. After simplifying the expression, we get $r=\frac{1}{n}$. Therefore, we can evaluate the sum of the series using the closed form, $S_n=\frac{a_1}{1-r}$. Substituting $r$, we get: $S_n=\dfrac{a_1}{1-\frac{1}{n}}$. After doing the algebraic manipulations, we get $S_n=\dfrac{m}{n-1}$, as desired.

Comment: Hint: $|n|>1$ means $\left|\frac1n\right|<1.$ This is a geometric series.

Comment: Your proof looks good. However, as mentioned in the above comment, you should verify that the series actually does converge.

Comment: What if $n<-1$, you'll then have alternating series, which obviously converges, but to what value?

Comment: @bb_823 The value of the geometric series is $\sum_{j=0}^\infty q^j = \frac{1}{1-q}$ for all $q\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\vert q \vert < 1$. In this case, $q = 1/n$. It doesn't matter which sign $n$ and hence $q$ has.

Comment: Interesting, it seems, that if $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then this property still holds, however if $n \notin\mathbb{Z}$, then the series seems to converge to a random(?) value.

Comment: @Csoriburi See my comment above, it doesn't matter if $n$ is an integer or a real number or even a complex number as long as $\vert n \vert > 1$.

Comment: @stange Yes, thank you for your answer. Sadly, I didn't see your comment in time. It is quite interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Another way is
to look at the partial sums
and use
$\dfrac{1-x^j}{1-x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{j-1} x^k
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\dfrac{m}{n^k}
&=\frac{m}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j}\frac{1}{n^{k-1}}\\
&=\dfrac{m}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\frac{1}{n^{k}}\\
&=\dfrac{m}{n}\dfrac{1-\frac1{n^j}}{1-\frac1{n}}\\
&=m\dfrac{1-\dfrac1{n^j}}{n-1}\\
&=\dfrac{m}{n-1}-\dfrac{m}{n^j(n-1)}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\dfrac{m}{n^k}-\dfrac{m}{n-1}\right|
=\dfrac{m}{n^j(n-1)}
$.

Therefore, to make
$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\dfrac{m}{n^k}-\dfrac{m}{n-1}\right|
\lt \delta
$,
is is enough to make
$\dfrac{m}{n^j(n-1)}
\lt \delta$,
and this can be done
by making $j$
large enough
so that
$n^j > \dfrac{m}{\delta(n-1)}
$.

If you are allowed
the use of logs,
this is just
$j
\gt \dfrac{\log(m)-\log(\delta(n-1))}{\log(n)}
$.

If not,
you can use Bernoulli's inequality
($(1+x)^j \ge 1+xj > xj$)
to have
$n^j = (1+(n-1))^j
\gt (n-1)j
$
so
$\dfrac{m}{n^j(n-1)}
\lt \dfrac{m}{j(n-1)(n-1)}
= \dfrac{m}{j(n-1)^2}
$.
Therefore, if
$\dfrac{m}{j(n-1)^2}
\lt \delta$,
or
$j > \dfrac{m}{\delta(n-1)^2}
$,
we have
$\dfrac{m}{n^j(n-1)}
\lt \delta$.

This is, of course,
much worse than
the inequality with log,
but it is completely elementary.